# Using Spring Beans in a class retrieved from DB via Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring

So I have a class, `PriceFeed`, that I retrieve from the database using Hibernate. This is necessary, as different products use different implementations of price feeds, each further distinguished by a set of properties.

Unfortunately, the price feed also needs to save the prices it retrieves, and update itself, each time a new set of prices is retrieved.

As far as I understand, this is done by a DAO implementation, commonly retrieved as a Spring bean.

Is there a way to get a Spring bean into the price feed automatically, when I load the row from the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Spring's `@Configurable` annotation on your `PriceFeed` class to autowire any fields. See http://www.olivergierke.de/wordpress/2009/05/using-springs-configurable-in-three-easy-steps/, though watch out for bugs like https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-5156.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is not the normal practice for a JPA implementation. It is more the Active Record style of DB access. I'm not offering a judgement on which is better here! :-)

If you want to inject something into an entity on load you could probably do it by implementing an Interceptor and implementing the onLoad method to inject a bean from the application context.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html